# Center section that is inside of a section

Tags: html, css

Can someone help a CSS newbie out?  I have a main section that then has a section inside of it.  I need to center the 2nd section inside the main section.  How can you do this?  Here is my code.

```css
.section1 {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.section2 {
    padding:10px; overflow:hidden;
    margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
        <section class="section2">
            <div>
                Registration Status
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegSts, new { disabled = true, size="10" })
                Admitting Program
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdmProg, new { disabled = true, size="10" })
                Academic Location
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Loc, new { disabled = true, size="10" })
                Division
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Div, new { disabled = true, size="10" })
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking...`section2` will be 100% wide by default and so, by definition, centered.

Comment: It doesn't though.  section 2 and the div inside it align to the left inside of  section 1.

Comment: The **contents** will stay left aligned because that's their default state...but that's not what you asked.

Comment: Oh!  Sorry I thought that was what I was asking. :) How can you change the default state from left aligned to center?  Is there a way to do it?  Thanks

Comment: If you want to center the text..use `text-align:center`.